# Joining LoginHistory to User using implicit parent-child relationship

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have been trying to bring in fields from the User object in my LoginHistory query. I keep getting an error saying the relationship is not understood even though there is a parent-child relationship.

select Userid, user.Username  from loginHistory

The above is not working and to me it seems its the simplest query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`LoginHistory.UserId.getDescribe()` shows "null" as the "relationshipName".
You can not join LoginHistory with User. I tried it but no luck. I fetched data locally and then applied the join.